# Git, where to put design papers?

Tags: git, git-flow

On the root directory of my git repository, I have a folder named "Design Papers" that I put all my designing and planning into. And I have a branch named `design_papers` for this folder solely.

Since this branch hypothetically will never finish until project ends, I keep rebasing `design_papers` branch onto `develop` branch each time a finished feature branch gets merged into `develop`.

Is there a better way to manage my design work inside git repository, or should I exclude them from repository and store somewhere else?

Comment: Why a separate branch? Keeping design notes in the same branch is fine, and likely useful for anyone reading your code.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Because I tend to plan ahead before even starting the feature. So If I put them in the feature branch, I might have 10-20 branches laying around and doing nothing but holding design notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with separate repository for documentation. This allows you to work either on code or on docs without moving around branches.

As far as I understand you don't want to keep code in sync with documentation **all the time**, probably just for releases (usually doc is part of the release). I would accomplish that by referencing in your code repo relevant doc-repo commit ID whenever you release a version (or reach some milestone, whatever). Even a simple text file with commit ID in it will work - for any milestone you can see which version of documentation is relevant

IMHO git works best with simple project structures without [subtree](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) / [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) stuff